# How to Copy a Node from XML without copying a child of that node using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a huge XML that i need to work on, but i only need a node of the several in the root. The problem is that, in that node, i got one child that need to be remove. Anyone care to explain if this is possible and, if it is, how can be done? 
This is a sample of the XML that i got:

```
    <XML>
 <Properties>
  Contend
 </Properties>
 <Events>
  Contend
 </Events>
 <Contracts>
  Contend
 </Contracts>
 <Trades>
  Contend 
 </Trades>
 <Deals>
  <Deal>
   <Edition>
    <Object>
     <Values>
      <Value>N</Value>
      <Value>N</Value>
     </Values>
    </Object>
    <Members>
     <memberValue>
      <member>template</member>
      <member>template</member>
      <member>
       <Object>
        <Flows>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <observations>
              Tons of Contend
             </observations>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <observations>
              Tons of Contend
             </observations>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <observations>
              Tons of Contend
             </observations>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <observations>
              Tons of Contend
             </observations>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
        </Flows>
       </Object>
      </member>
     </memberValue>
    </Members>
   </Edition>
  </Deal>
 </Deals>
</XML>
```

I need to preserve de  Node, but, inside, i need to remove the  one. Please note that the  node repeats in each of the  node. All of them must be removed.

In the end, my XML shoul'd look like this:

```
    <XML>
 <Deals>
  <Deal>
   <Edition>
    <Object>
     <Values>
      <Value>N</Value>
      <Value>N</Value>
     </Values>
    </Object>
    <Members>
     <memberValue>
      <member>template</member>
      <member>template</member>
      <member>
       <Object>
        <Flows>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
         <Cupom>
          <Period>
           <Calculation>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Data>N</Data>
            <Rate>
             <Data>N</Data>
             <Data>N</Data>
            </Rate>
           </Calculation>
          </Period>
         </Cupom>
        </Flows>
       </Object>
      </member>
     </memberValue>
    </Members>
   </Edition>
  </Deal>
 </Deals>
</XML>
```

Many thanks for anyone that can help.

Cheers!

Comment: Edit your question and re-mark your document sample.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a short and completely in the spirit of XSLT solution. I also formatted your XML documents in order to be visible to the reraders.

Comment: The format of the code whas inappropriate? Sorry if it was. I will read the rules for posting and tips for newbies. Many tanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(self::Deals)] | Cupom/*/*/*/observations"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when performed against the provided XML document, produces the wanted result.**

Comment: good answer and good edit! Also, I don't see other `observations` element. I guess the expression `Cupom/*/*/*/observations` is for clarity.

Comment: @Alexandro, Yes it could be only `match="observations"` -- I just didn't have the time to scrutinize the complete big document. :)